# OpenSSL command line input data length

Tags: openssl, aes

With the OpenSSL CLI, I am getting an error with a 16-byte input string

`echo -e "abcdefgh\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nopad -a -K 6162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F707172737475767778797A303132333435 -iv 61636567696B6D6F7173757779303234`

stating

> bad decrypt
>   140550741059328:error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:437

but if I alter the input string length to 15 bytes, `abcdefgh\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08`, the error does not occur. It occurs for 13, 14, 16 and 17-byte input. Not tried other lengths.

Given AES 256 CBC has a block length of 16 bytes, I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The echo adds a carriage return after the string, making the data to encrypt 17 bytes instead of 16.

So the openssl error is correct: `data not multiple of block length`

You should use the `-n` option of `echo`:

```
echo -ne "abcdefgh\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nopad -K 6162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F707172737475767778797A303132333435 -iv 61636567696B6D6F7173757779303234
```